# svmtrain - Specify the cost for missclassification

Tags: matlab, classification, svm

Matlab offers the command fitcsvm to train an svm. In it, you can pass a key-value pair called Cost, which specifies a custom miss-classification penalty for the SVM for each class. Since I'm using an older version of matlab, I need to use svmtrain. However, I cannot find such a key-value pair for the function. Is there any way I could do so?

Comment: What exactly is measured by the `miss-classification penalty`?

Comment: The cost of the false negative vs the cost of the false positives. I have a two-class svm in which having a false positive is way more destructive than having a false negative.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to work with `fitcsvm`. there is an option like what you want in `ClassificationTree.fit`. I think the only option related is `soft margin` you could set it to `inf` to have a hard margin but it affects FP and FN the same.

Comment: Are you talking about the `boxconstraint` parameter in `svmtrain` in MATLAB?

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar, He wants to adjust the classifier so he could have less false positive no matter how many false negatives, and that can't be adjusted by `boxconstraint`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cost parameter of an C-SVM is also called "boxconstraint". Please see its usage details in [this index](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/svmtrain.html).

An C-SVM with different cost parameters for each class is called 2C-SVM. It is important to know that this strategy is best suitable for dealing with unbalanced binany datasets, in which the number of samples in one the classes is much higher than the other. A good pair of misclassifications costs in this 2C-SVM technique can also reduce the ratio of false positives (or false negatives) on balanced datasets, but it is usually very costly to optimize those parameters. If you have time, take a look on a technique called "bias shifting". With this technique, you train an C-SVM model with a single cost parameter and after that you increase (or decrease) the bias (b) parameter to control the ratio of false positives (or false negatives). It is much faster than 2C-SVM and gives comparable results.

Comment: But the description of the box constraint says it bounds the error. I just want to give more weight to certain errors. Or am I misunderstanding it?

Comment: Description says: "C can be a scalar, or a vector of the same length as the training data. If C is a scalar, it is automatically rescaled by N/(2*N1) for the data points of group one and by N/(2*N2) for the data points of group two, where N1 is the number of elements in group one, N2 is the number of elements in group two, and N = N1 + N2".

Thus, when C is a scalar, the weights are set automatically to take into account unbalanced data. To give a custom weight for each class, you need to set it as an array of weights, with elements of class one weighted as "X" and elements of class B as "Y".

Comment: So if C is given as a vector, I basically assign each data point a custom weight for missclassification?

Comment: Yes, but the C-array is not just the weights. Its a list of weighted C parameters. For instance, if you chose your C parameter to be 1, and now you want to weight false positives *three* times more than false negatives, your C-array could be like: [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, ..., 1.5, 1.5, 1.5]. The first values for the positive class and the last ones for the negative class. For an C equal to 2, the values could be: [1, 1, 1, ..., 3, 3, 3].

Selection of a good "C" parameter is a different story. There are many techniques to do that. Grid-search is a simple one.

Comment: I thought the value of C was that which I input into the field "boxconstraints". How exactly do I specify C and additionally specify a C-array? E.g I want to weigh the false positives 5 times more, I pass a vector to 'boxconstraint' with the values [0.5 0.5, ..., 2.5 2.5] the index of the first values corresponding to the index of the positives, and the index of the latter values corresponding to the index of the negatives, according to what you wrote. You also stated that for these values, my C parameter has to be one. How to I specify that?

Comment: Sorry for the double comment: If it makes it easier, could you specify a sample svmtrain which weighs the false positives 5 times more than the false negatives. E.g svmtrain(features, labels, 'boxconstraint', ...)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to classify false positives with greater accuracy than false negatives, I think you can pass `C` as a vector. Please read [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31066/what-is-the-influence-of-c-in-svms-with-linear-kernel) and [this](http://www.svms.org/parameters/) to understand what `C` does in SVM. I quote from the second link given:

> "However, it is critical here, as in any regularization scheme, that a proper value is chosen for C, the penalty factor. If it is too large, we have a high penalty for nonseparable points and we may store many support vectors and overfit. If it is too small, we may have underfitting."
>   Alpaydin (2004), page 224.

So, you may pass large values of `C` for false positives and tiny values of `C` for false negatives. You have to take care of lot of other factors, for example, overfitting and under-performing. Usually, setting a large value for `C` achieves a good performance on train but it worsens on test set due to overfitting. A (very) tiny value of `C` may ignore constraints and produce a sub-optimal classification result i.e. you may be able to get a *significantly* higher performance with a different value of `C`. To avoid this, you can do cross-validation. I have never tried this.

Comment: But the description of the box constraint says it bounds the error. I just want to give more weight to certain errors. Or am I misunderstanding it?

Comment: I think if you give C as an array of values, and if you give large values of C for false positive, there will be a large penalty and those values will get correctly classified (so less error). Vice-versa for false negatives. You have to try with different parameters.